# javascript error: missing ) after argumen in robot framework

Tags: javascript, testing, scroll, robotframework

```
Execute JavaScript       document.evaluate('(//span[text()='Create'])[2]',document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

I am not missing anything, still i am getting error. In my case Scroll down operation is not working. I am trying to click directly using java script with out scrolling , still i am getting this error.

For scroll down i used this script `[Arguments]    ${location}
    #Execute Javascript    window.document.evaluate(${location}, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);`

Comment: `'(//span[text()='Create'])[2]'` - you are closing the string prematurely. Option 1: Use a combination of singlee quotes, double quotes, or backticks to make that string Option 2: escape the inner single quotes.

Comment: Thanks ..Issue resolved